How to export Oracle schema which is CDB and ORACLE_MAINTAINED=Y?
Using Oracle's expdp to export a schema on a CDB database where schema was created in the root using
alter session set "_oracle_script"=TRUE;
Tried following command:
expdp MySchema/pwd@instance DUMPFILE=MySchema.dmp

but it gives small dump file of 308KB.
Parameters  CONTENT=ALL, INCLUDE=TABLE:"IN ('TABLE_LIST')" have no sense.
That schema's ORACLE_MAINTAINED=Y and tables are also ORACLE_MAINTAINED=Y.
Export log is:
Export: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Nov 29 11:46:41 2024
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production

Warning: Oracle Data Pump operations are not typically needed when connected to the root or seed of a container database.

Starting "MYSCHEMA"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01":  MYSCHEMA/********@instance
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/DEFAULT_ROLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLESPACE_QUOTA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/COMMENT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Master table "MYSCHEMA"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for MYSCHEMA.SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01 is:
  C:\PATH\DPDUMP\EXPDAT.DMP
Job "MYSCHEMA"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully completed at Fri Nov 29 04:47:50 2024 elapsed 0 00:00:37

Though there are 100+ tables with data.

Just want to confirm that you are actually inserting the table names you want to export in place of 'TABLE_LIST'

That parameter won't help, @CaffeinatedCod3r

and what do you have in the dumpfile?

@gsalem added export log to the question.

By design, expdp does not export oracle maintained schemas. So you're stuck here. Why did you put _oracle_script=true, with all the warnings about not doing it? they are given whenever this setting is mentioned?Look at note 2114233.1 on support.oracle.com. The only solution is to copy the data to a 'normal' schema

@gsalem how copy data does look like? is it CREATE NEW_SCHEMA_TABLE AS SELECT * OLD_SCHEMA_TABLE?

You have to copy to another schema: create table new_schema.x as select * from old_schema.x. Then you can export the new_schema

yeah @gsalem used that and it worked for data in tables, tyvm! pitty not that trivial to move altogether views, stored procedures, etc.

This schema has tables, but the tables don't have data, right?
Try this query: select sum(bytes/1024/1024) from user_segments; --To find out the size of your user.
Have you tried backup/restore with RMAN?

tables do have data. RMAN sounds like an overkill in CI/CD pipeline

Sorry but i cant comment before.
Try export just one table with data please?

yup, @Eduardo, will try whenever I can
